# How to set timeout on $.ajax request and redo it if it takes too long?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can someone show me a practical example on setting a timeout to my $.ajax request and redo the entire request if the first request is timed out, I've read the docs and didn't get it. I will appreciate any help.

Here is my $.ajax request.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/ajax/product.php',
        type: 'get',
        data: {product_id : product_id},
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#details').html('<div class="loading"></div>');
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('.iosSlider').fadeOut('fast');
            thisprod.addClass('current');
            $('#details').css({opacity: 0}).html(data).stop().animate({left: 0, opacity: 1}, 800);
        }
    });
    return false;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resend a failed ajax request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881614/how-do-i-resend-a-failed-ajax-request)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function takes a timeout parameter and you can check the status in case of error.

```
var call =function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/ajax/product.php',
        type: 'get',
        timeout: 400,
        ...
        error: function(x, textStatus, m) {
            if (textStatus=="timeout") {
                 call();
            }
        }
    });
};
```

You might want to make something a little smarter to avoid permanent calls...

From the documentation :

> Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. This will override
>   any global timeout set with $.ajaxSetup(). The timeout period starts
>   at the point the $.ajax call is made; if several other requests are in
>   progress and the browser has no connections available, it is possible
>   for a request to time out before it can be sent. In jQuery 1.4.x and
>   below, the XMLHttpRequest object will be in an invalid state if the
>   request times out; accessing any object members may throw an
>   exception. In Firefox 3.0+ only, script and JSONP requests cannot be
>   cancelled by a timeout; the script will run even if it arrives after
>   the timeout period.

Comment: This will work if there is only one kind i.e. url to which requests are made. Neat answer, nonetheless! :)

Answer (score 0):

a. You can maintain a queue of all the requests that you make.

```
$.xhrQueue = [];
```

---

b. Enqueue  each request that you make

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (e, xhr) {  
            $.xhrQueue .push(xhr);
        }
});
```

---

c. Poll for which requests completed vs timed-out

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.each($.xhrQueue, function (xhr) {
       //check whether status is complete, 
       //with some try-catch you can know which were the timed-out/not-sent ones

    });
}, 1000);
```

<sub>Note: If not `beforeSend`, you can go via some other function through which you attempt to make an ajax call</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I would use the jquery deferred fail callback for this case.
http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/

Answer (score -1):

***Try this***

```
var setTime = setTimeOut(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php bloginfo('
        template_directory ');?>/ajax/product.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            'product_id': product_id
        }
    }).beforeSend(function() {
        $('#details').html('<div class="loading"></div>');
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('.iosSlider').fadeOut('fast');
        thisprod.addClass('current');
        $('#details').css({
            opacity: 0
        }).html(data).stop().animate({
            left: 0,
            opacity: 1
        }, 800);
    });
}, 2000);
```