# jQuery re-send ajax call after success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to be able to re-send an AJAX request (using jQuery) after is has been completed. This was my initial implementation

```
$.ajaxSetup({  
  complete: function(xhr, status) {
    $.ajax(xhr)
  }
});
```

But it seems as though I haven't understood the documentation as this doesn't fire off a request to the same URL.

Is there a way to complete this?

(p.s. I understand that if the above example was to work, that it would be an infinite loop of the same ajax request, this has been reduced for example purposes only :) )

Comment: What's the original task?

Comment: Just a standard $.ajax({...some config...})

Comment: does this answer help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11602555/2421292

Comment: The first argument to `$.ajax` is either a URL string or a settings object. Where did you get the idea you could pass an XHR object?

Comment: Just made two kinda mirror functions...when one is a success, then call the other

Answer (score 7):

Just do

```
$.ajax({
    url: "foo.cfc",
    success: function(){
        $.ajax(this);
    }
})
```

`this` is the settings passed in.

The same works for completed, but your question title asks for success.