# Resend the same ajax call by it's variable

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here's my code :

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: 'some.url'    
});
request.done(function(result){
    console.log(result);
});
request.fail(function(result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

My question is: Is there any way to initiate the same ajax call with just the variable name (In this case it's `request`) ???

Like: `request.SomeMethodToCallSameAjax();`

Comment: Try looking at

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881614/how-do-i-resend-a-failed-ajax-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function:

```
var myAjax = function() {
  return request = $.ajax({
     url: 'some.url'    
  });
}

myAjax.done(function(result) { console.log(result); }
myAjax.fail(function(result) { console.log(result); }
```

When you need to:

```
//Call my function
myAjax();
```

Comment: Thanks :) That's what I wanted. But I think `myAjax.done()` wont work. Instead there should be `myAjax().done()`